# Oracle Linux 8 to 9 in place upgrade with Leapp fails with XFS internal log size 8192 too large, must be less than 4789

Tags: linux, redhat, oracle

Can someone please help?

```
2023-11-14 09:25:01.774 DEBUG    PID: 308200 leapp.workflow.InterimPreparation.dnf_dry_run: External command has finished: 

['/bin/dd', 'if=/dev/zero', 'of=/var/lib/leapp/scratch/diskimages/root_boot', 'bs=1M', 'count=0', 'seek=75']

2023-11-14 09:25:01.775 DEBUG    PID: 308200 leapp.workflow.InterimPreparation.dnf_dry_run: Creating XFS filesystem in disk image at /var/lib/leapp/scratch/diskimages/root_boot

2023-11-14 09:25:01.776 DEBUG    PID: 308200 leapp.workflow.InterimPreparation.dnf_dry_run: External command has started: ['/sbin/mkfs.xfs', '-l', 'size=32m', '-f', '/var/lib/leapp/scratch/diskimages/root_boot']

internal log size 8192 too large, must be less than 4789

Usage: mkfs.xfs

/* blocksize */         [-b size=num]

/* metadata */          [-m crc=0|1,finobt=0|1,uuid=xxx,rmapbt=0|1,reflink=0|1]

/* data subvol */       [-d agcount=n,agsize=n,file,name=xxx,size=num,

                            (sunit=value,swidth=value|su=num,sw=num|noalign),

                            sectsize=num

/* force overwrite */   [-f]

/* inode size */        [-i perblock=n|size=num,maxpct=n,attr=0|1|2,

                            projid32bit=0|1,sparse=0|1]

/* no discard */        [-K]

/* log subvol */        [-l agnum=n,internal,size=num,logdev=xxx,version=n

                            sunit=value|su=num,sectsize=num,lazy-count=0|1]

/* label */             [-L label (maximum 12 characters)]

/* naming */            [-n size=num,version=2|ci,ftype=0|1]

/* no-op info only */   [-N]

/* prototype file */    [-p fname]

/* quiet */             [-q]

/* realtime subvol */   [-r extsize=num,size=num,rtdev=xxx]

/* sectorsize */        [-s size=num]

/* version */           [-V]

                        devicename

<devicename> is required unless -d name=xxx is given.

<num> is xxx (bytes), xxxs (sectors), xxxb (fs blocks), xxxk (xxx KiB),

      xxxm (xxx MiB), xxxg (xxx GiB), xxxt (xxx TiB) or xxxp (xxx PiB).

<value> is xxx (512 byte blocks).
```

.

```
2023-11-14 09:25:01.822 DEBUG    PID: 308200 leapp.workflow.InterimPreparation.dnf_dry_run: Command ['/sbin/mkfs.xfs', '-l', 'size=32m', '-f', '/var/lib/leapp/scratch/diskimages/root_boot'] failed with exit code 1.

2023-11-14 09:25:01.825 DEBUG    PID: 308200 leapp.workflow.InterimPreparation.dnf_dry_run: External command has finished: ['/sbin/mkfs.xfs', '-l', 'size=32m', '-f', '/var/lib/leapp/scratch/diskimages/root_boot']

2023-11-14 09:25:01.826 ERROR    PID: 308200 leapp.workflow.InterimPreparation.dnf_dry_run: Failed to create XFS filesystem /var/lib/leapp/scratch/diskimages/root_boot

Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "/etc/leapp/repos.d/system_upgrade/common/libraries/overlaygen.py", line 386, in _format_disk_image_xfs

    utils.call_with_oserror_handled(cmd=cmd)

  File "/etc/leapp/repos.d/system_upgrade/common/libraries/utils.py", line 119, in call_with_oserror_handled

    run(cmd)

  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/leapp/libraries/stdlib/__init__.py", line 188, in run

    result=result

leapp.libraries.stdlib.CalledProcessError: Command ['/sbin/mkfs.xfs', '-l', 'size=32m', '-f', '/var/lib/leapp/scratch/diskimages/root_boot'] failed with exit code 1.

2023-11-14 09:25:01.829 DEBUG    PID: 308200 leapp.workflow.InterimPreparation.dnf_dry_run: Cleaning up mounts

2023-11-14 09:25:01.830 DEBUG    PID: 308200 leapp.workflow.InterimPreparation.dnf_dry_run: Recursively removing scratch directory /var/lib/leapp/scratch.

2023-11-14 09:25:01.839 DEBUG    PID: 308200 leapp.workflow.InterimPreparation.dnf_dry_run: Recursively removed scratch directory /var/lib/leapp/scratch.

2023-11-14 09:25:01.863 INFO     PID: 244972 leapp.workflow: Workflow interrupted due to FailImmediately error policy

2023-11-14 09:25:01.910 INFO     PID: 244972 leapp: Answerfile will be created at /var/log/leapp/answerfile
```

.

```
[root@mffzzz03-temp boot]# df -h

Filesystem                   Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on

devtmpfs                      69G     0   69G   0% /dev

tmpfs                         69G     0   69G   0% /dev/shm

tmpfs                         69G   26M   69G   1% /run

tmpfs                         69G     0   69G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup

/dev/mapper/rootvg-root       53G  6.4G   44G  13% /

/dev/mapper/rootvg-home      975M   11M  898M   2% /home

/dev/mapper/rootvg-usrlocal  2.9G  160K  2.8G   1% /usr/local

/dev/mapper/rootvg-opt       975M   24K  908M   1% /opt

/dev/sdb1                    281M  183M   80M  70% /boot

/dev/mapper/applvg-u01        79G  1.7G   73G   3% /u01

/dev/mapper/applvg-u02        99G  4.1G   90G   5% /u02

/dev/mapper/datavg-data      394G   24K  374G   1% /data

/dev/mapper/rootvg-var        24G  7.4G   16G  33% /var

/dev/mapper/datavg-reco      600G   14G  586G   3% /reco

/dev/mapper/rootvg-tmp       4.8G  9.5M  4.6G   1% /tmp

tmpfs                         14G   12K   14G   1% /run/user/42

tmpfs                         14G     0   14G   0% /run/user/9999

 

5.4.17-2136.325.5.el8uek.x86_64 #2 SMP Thu Oct 19 15:08:42 PDT 2023 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 1):

Check if you have sufficient disk space in /boot/. The partition must have at least 250 MB of disk space to accommodate the installation.
https://docs.oracle.com/en/operating-systems/oracle-linux/9/leapp/leapp-AboutLeapp.html#upgrade-cond

Comment: `dev/sdb1                    281M  183M   80M  70% /boot` looks like it was buried in the output.